# How can I display a large number of google map markers without resorting to using an object literal for each instance of a marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a constructor that I use to initialize each location object that I want to indicate with a google map marker. For each location object, I would like to assign a marker and infoWindow within the object constructor as I have done below for instances of the object 'Site'.

```
var Site = function (position, lat, lng, zoom, heading, pitch) {
    var self = this;
    self.position = position;
    self.lat = lat;
    self.lng = lng;
    self.zoom = zoom;
    self.heading = heading;
    self.pitch = pitch;

    self.mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: self.lat, lng: self.lng},
      map: bayarea,
      title: self.position
    });
    self.infoWindow = new google.maps.infoWindow({
      content: self.position
    });
    self.infoWindow.addListener('click', function() {
      self.infoWindow.open(map, self.mapMarker);
    });
};
```

I initialize the google map object with the default setter:

```
window.initMap = function() {
  var center = {lat: 37.656, lng: -122.288};
  var bayarea = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: center
  });
};
```

The map renders, but I am unable to create markers and infoWindows that are properties of each location object **unless I create an object literal for each marker and infoWindow instantiation**. I have searched through the googlemaps JavaScript API documentation, but I cannot figure out a solution that enables me to manage my markers so that I do not have to dedicate 10 lines of code to each declaration and assignment.

How can I effectively instantiate and manage a large set of markers with the googleMaps JS API?

===========================================================================
for reference, the siteDatabase object

```
var siteDatabase = {
    alamedasite : new Site('Jack London Square', 37.7947939, -122.2770558, 12, 252.63, 106.37),
    contracostasite : new Site('Mount Diablo', 37.8817588, -121.9140186, 12, 271.67, 100.56),
    marinsite : new Site('Golden Gate Bridge', 37.8187103, -122.4721451, 12, 252.63, 99.56),
    napasite : new Site('Downtown Napa', 38.2984241, -122.2842797, 12, 118.22, 90.31),
    sfsite : new Site('Skyline', 37.7403805, -122.4201316, 12, 29.08, 87.21),
    sanmateosite : new Site('Pulgas Water Temple', 37.4835189, -122.3162989, 12, 169.64, 87.87),
    santaclarasite : new Site('Computer History Museum', 37.4137657, -122.0780323,  12, 57.07, 94.97),
    solanocountysite : new Site('Mare Island Historical Park', 38.0980429, -122.2710533, 12,  304.72, 87.53),
    sonomacountysite : new Site('Bodega Bay', 38.3015501, -123.0568967, 12, 241.82, 93.6),
    santacruzsite : new Site('Henry Cowell State Park', 37.0382202, -122.0627259, 12, 332.28, 158)
};
```

Comment: did you try clustered markers?

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.infoWindow is not a constructor` (because it isn't, javascript is case sensitive, the correct constructor is `google.maps.InfoWindow)`; once that is fixed the other typo is you are adding the click listener to the InfoWindow (self.infoWindow.addListener), when that should be the marker (self.mapMarker.addListener). [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se9d62ue/)

Comment: Adding to what @geocodezip said, please note the need to `bayarea` to be declared in the global scope (or at least a scope that is visible to `initMap` and `Site` as well. You current declaration is visible only for `initMap`

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful. I made some other changes so that the markers and declared within the map initialize function. If I push the markers to an array I can log them to console, but the markers do not show up on the map. [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nomad343/se9d62ue/21/)